# Your opinion on using no-scale option for mobile devices (HTML)

Tags: html

I am creating a template and I have faced the question weather I need to include

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

by default or just to use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

The template works for building layouts. And they will be responsive in most cases. That is why I want to include the no-scale option by default. Do you think it is a good idea? Do people really need it when they are creating the web app? I have just seen the article that tells no to do so. But it looks very shady and I don't want to trust it that easily. Here it is: http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have just seen the article that tells no to do so.

I don't really understand your doubts, since the page you've linked says:

> If you are not coding a responsive site, just don’t use any meta
>   viewport. **If you are coding a responsive website, all you need to
>   write is**
>
> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Often people tell you to not use `maximum-scale=1` and they are right, but the line that I have quoted here is really helpful and let's say required for responsive web pages.

Comment: How do you think, in the majority of cases, people now days build responsive web applications?

Comment: Nowadays responsive web design is the must have of every well-made web application if this is what you're asking about.

Comment: Great, thank you for your opinion) Really cheered me up)